# CNAME | A-Record | MX Record | Problems

Tags: domains, multiple-domains, cname

I have a domain (e.g. domain1.com) and I only want to CNAME re-point the A-Record to domain2.com

CNAME re-pointing will affect both A-Record and MX-Record.

I do not want to affect the MX record, but I need CNAME re-pointing because I want all the viewed website pages to be domain1.com sub-pages, (not domain2.com sub-pages).

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add details about web server software?  You may not need DNS cnames at all

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the root of a domain to be a CNAME, at least not as easy as you think.
[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656009/how-to-overcome-root-domain-cname-restrictions) has details about how you might want to go about this.